# Division exception in MYSQL or Python

Tags: python

I would like to automate the division by 0. Some of variable extracted from db might equal 0 and division would give an error. Should I make an exception In DB or in python code?

Comment: you could put it in a try block

Comment: You can add `try` and `except` directly when you do division

Comment: Can you please give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is better:

```
for b in varb:
    try:
        v = 1/b # or any code that raises division by zero
        print(v)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print(0)
```

Comment: should I put it in every formula? I tried to put return 0 instead of print (0). But it does not work. how to make it just return 0 instead of printing?

Comment: @Gunel I think I will need more code form you to answer that question. can you post and share your desire a bit clear?

Comment: I want the code be applicable to other formulas so that the code if detects 0 it returns 0 rather than an error. As I understood I need to write your code for each formula? is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

```
data  = [1,2,0,3,4,0,0,5]
updated_data = [0 if i==0 else 1/i for i in data]
print(updated_data)
```

Here, data is simple data you required. I have used list comprehension to create new list with 1/x or 0.

It will check if i =0, it will execute instruction written before if that is 0. Else, it will execute else part that is 1/i.

It creates new list and assign to the variable declare.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `continue` statement with `if else` statement to avoid the divisible by zero error like this way

```
m=10

b=7

varb=[var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8]
for b in varb:
    if b==0: 
      print ("Not Devisible by zero")
      continue
    else:
      print (m/b)
```